# Tikz Interdependence representation

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm having a lot of trouble with expressing two representation of Qualiflyer and Star Airline Alliances with clear and comprehensible illustration. I am pretty sure it should be done with tikzpicture but I am struggling with the nodes and getting no results. Could you please help me with that? Sorry for not providing you any code, but I have really no idea from where to start. Thank you so much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I saw an almost identical question (same graphs) just the other day.  Homework?

Comment: Maybe, but homework done in LaTeX! @rjkvc, you might want to have a look at the mindmap chapter from the tikz manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tri/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, draw, text width=10mm, align=center, inner sep=1pt}]

\node[tri, text width=20mm] (sw) {Swissair\\ SR\\ +22 others};
\foreach \i [count=\ni from 0] in {AOM Fr, Turkish, {Sabena\\ SN}, {Portu\-galia}, {Air\\  Littoral}, Volare, Crossair, {LOT\\ Polish\\ LO}, {Air\\ Europe}, {TAP\\ Portugal}}
\node[tri, font=\small] at (\ni*36:5cm) (\ni) {\i};

\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,8,9}
\draw (sw) -- (\i);

\foreach \i in {4,5,6,7}
\draw[dashed] (sw) -- (\i);

\draw (2) to[out=-80, in=150] (0);
\draw (2) to[out=-90, in=120] (9);

\draw[dashed] ([xshift=-5mm]sw)--([xshift=-5mm]3);

\draw[dashed] ([yshift=-5mm]sw)--([yshift=-5mm]0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]